# Filling table via AJAX, it goes beyond page limits but there's no scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a table on my page that's filled dynamically via AJAX. Sometimes, the results are so many that they go too far down the page. Yet, there's no scrollbar or anything! I tried setting the html attribute 'overflow' to 'scroll'. but the scrollbar doesn't activate after the AJAX request.

How can I deal with that?

Comment: you will have to show some code..

Comment: also, it's probably got nothing to do with AJAX, only CSS.